# MATLAB program for finite difference method for y'' + e^y = 0

Tags: matlab, solver, differential-equations

Consider the following boundary value problem:

```
y'' + e^y = 0 i.e. y(0) = y(1) = 0.
```

I am curious about how MATLAB will solve the finite difference method for this particular problem. I know that if we have a linear ODE, e.g. `y'' + (e^x)y = 0`, with the same boundary conditions, then the program is fairly simple. Say we use the partition of the interval [0,1] into 20 equal sub-intervals, then the following code will work:

```
N = 19;
h = 1/N;
x = linspace(0, 1, N+1)';
A(1,1) = 1;
F(1) = 0;

for k=2:N
  A(k,k-1) = -1/h^2;
  A(k,k)   = 2/h^2+exp(x(k));
  A(k,k+1) = -1/h^2;
  F(k) = 0;
end

A(N+1, N+1)=1;
F(N+1) = 0;
U = A\F';
```

However it seems that my question is very different from this simple example, because we are dealing with systems of nonlinear equations. How should we formulate the code in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Matlab inbuilt differential equation solvers. You can use `ode45, bvp4c` etc. Your equation can be re written as following set of equations. Let  `y = x1` and `ydot = x2`, you will get
`x1dot = x2`

`x2dot = -e^(x1)`

With your boundary conditions this can be solved using `[bvp4c]`[1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html)

```
function SOQ
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,1,5),[0 0]);% initial guess taken as [0 0]
sol = bvp4c(@ode,@bouncond,solinit);
x = linspace(0,1);
y = deval(sol,x);
plot(x,y(1,:));
end

function dydx = ode(x,y) % system of equations
dydx = [y(2);-exp(y(1))];
end

function res = bouncond(ya,yb) % boundary conditions
res = [ya(1);yb(1)];
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need an iterative solver. In the most simple case repeatedly solve with

```
  A(k,k-1) = -1/h^2;
  A(k,k)   = 2/h^2;
  A(k,k+1) = -1/h^2;

  F(k) = -exp(y(k));
```

For a Newton-like procedure, compute the next approximation `u` as having a small difference to `y` so that `e^u=e^y*e^(u-y)=e^y*(1+(u-y)+..)` so that the linearized equation to solve is

```
u'' + e^y*u = F(x) = -e^y*(1-y)
```

that is

```
  A(k,k-1) = -1/h^2;
  A(k,k)   = 2/h^2 + exp(y(k));
  A(k,k+1) = -1/h^2;

  F(k) = -exp(y(k))*(1-y(k));
```